# Javascript Canvas fillRect transparent black

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm developing a resource monitor with JavaScript, and I pretend to complete it with an cool background animation.

I'm having trouble with fillRect and transparent colors in fillStyle, eg.:

```
        function draw() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#00FF00";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(getRandom(0, c.width),getRandom(0,c.height),25,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.arc(getRandom(0, c.width),getRandom(0,c.height),25,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
```

It works fine, but it doesn't fill completely, leaving some "ghosts" where circles already passed before.

There is anyway to fix this and make background pure black again?

Notes:
I can't draw pure black, because I want the drawed lines smoothly disappear

Image of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrPxX.png
Note that yellow dots are most recent lines, orange are transitional lines, which give the smooth effect, and red dot are the "ghosts"

Comment: Draw the background again before drawing the rectangle

Comment: I don't get your issue : if the figures smoothly disappear, then they leave a ghost... ? Could you share a picture of your issue ?

Comment: PS : for anyone interested, jsbin here : http://jsbin.com/barurekeseto/1/edit  i don't see no ghost (latest Chrome/macOS)

Comment: Screenshot added to main post... also i tested your code and same happened

Comment: So what happens is that the lines stay forever ? I don't the issue with my jsbin and you do, so you should precise Browser / Browser version / OS. If other S.O. people could tell if they see the issue with their Browser/OS that would be great.

Comment: I'm using latest Chrome with updated Win7

Answer (score 1):

When you fill the rectangle, you're using a semi-transparent black. What that will do is to darken what's there, but it won't obliterate it, because it's semi-transparent. If you want to cover it up with pure black, either set full opacity (max alpha value), or else use an rgb colour rather than rgba. If you use rgb, the alpha value will implicitly be set to opaque.

Comment: I want to reach pure black smoothly, that's why i'm using an alpha value... but it stacks on a "ghost" color